# Sending 502 response: application did not send a complete response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, passenger

I am getting 502 status. My secret key is in place. Following are my nginx logs :

```
App 30246 stderr: [ 2016-04-30 04:49:19.3459 30370/0x00000004a0b6b8(Worker 1) utils.rb:85 ]: *** Exception ActionController::RoutingError in Rack application object (No route matches [GET] "/login") (process 30370, thread 0x00000004a0b6b8(Worker 1)):
App 30246 stderr:   from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
App 30246 stderr:   from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
App 30246 stderr:   from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
App 30246 stderr:   from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
App 30246 stderr:   from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
App 30246 stderr:   from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
App 30246 stderr:   from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
App 30246 stderr:   from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
App 30246 stderr:   from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
App 30246 stderr:   from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
App 30246 stderr:   from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
App 30246 stderr:   from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
App 30246 stderr:   from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/sentry-raven-0.15.1/lib/raven/integrations/rack.rb:54:in `call'
App 30246 stderr:   from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
App 30246 stderr:   from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
App 30246 stderr:   from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:94:in `process_request'
App 30246 stderr:   from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:149:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
App 30246 stderr:   from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:110:in `main_loop'
App 30246 stderr:   from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:415:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
App 30246 stderr:   from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:111:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'
[ 2016-04-30 04:49:19.3466 30034/7ff48160c700 age/Cor/Req/Utils.cpp:95 ]: [Client 1-4] Sending 502 response: application did not send a complete response
```

Comment: Do you solve this question?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set [`passenger_intercept_errors`](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_intercept_errors) to `on` in your nginx configuration (the configuration name is misleading), otherwise Passenger will continue to intercept errors. Setting this to `on` will drop them to nginx's `error_page` directives.

Comment: Hi there, is something similar to apache?

Comment: @mariomol Set `PassengerErrorOverride` to `on` https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/apache/reference/#passengererroroverride

Comment: thanks for answering.. in my case i found out a bug in the code that was leading to this..thanks!